# Destructure object, remove array when passing to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object-destructuring

I would like to pass the paging data to my component without passing the docs array.

```json
"docs": [
   
],
"totalDocs": 18,
"offset": 0,
"limit": 10,
"totalPages": 2,
"page": 1,
"pagingCounter": 1,
"hasPrevPage": false,
"hasNextPage": true,
"prevPage": null,
"nextPage": 2
```

I am setting the state from my axios get:

```
const queryFunction = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios(configFetch)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data); // update state with response
        })
```

However, I am passing all of the data to my component, how can I just pass the paging data without the docs array?

```
<Pager {...data} />
```

Comment: I think we can't exclude a specific. How about `{...data, docs: []}` ? Explicitly initialize it with empty array or even `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [spread (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) out the `docs`, then capture 'the rest' and pass that to your `<Pager />`:

```
const { docs, ...otherProps } = data;

return <Pager {...otherProps} />
```

---

Runnable demo to show how it's working:

```js
const obj = {
    docs: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
};

const { docs, ...otherProps } = obj;
console.log(otherProps)
```